# Multiple selections in Listbox userform and storing multiple listbox values as one array into the excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have the following code on a command button that initializes in a Listbox on a Userform and pastes the value into "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sub")".

This only works with one selection, and if you select multiple selections in the Listbox it will only add the first value to cell A8 in column 5.

I want user to be able to pick several options from a listbox. Then, when they save the form, I want the options they selected to populate in the next available row as an Array in the Excel sheet:

```
Private Sub cmdadd_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sub")
    wks.Activate
    Dim i As Integer
    ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Select
    i = 1
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = Empty
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'move down 1 row
        i = i + 1 'keep a count of the ID for later use
    Loop
    'Populate the new data values into the 'Sub' worksheet.
    ActiveCell.Value = i 'Next ID number
    'Populate the new data values into the 'Sub' worksheet.
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.txtls.Text 'set col B
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.txtPr.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.cbolo.Text

    Dim intOffset As Integer
    Dim strVal As String
    Dim selRange As Range

    Set selRange = Selection
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
     If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
      If strApps = "" Then
       strApps = ListBox1.List(i)
       intOffset = i
       strVal = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value 'set col E
      Else
       strApps = strApps & ";" & ListBox1.List(i)
       intOffset = i
       strVal = strVal & ";" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value 'set col E
     End If
    End If
   Next
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.ListBox1.AddItem "A"
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem "3"
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem "S"
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem "2"
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem "S"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: you'd better add some screenshots to explain wanted behavior in more detail

Comment: @DisplayName I have updated the image

Comment: and what's the current output of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid Select/Active/Selection/ActiveXXX coding pattern and rely on fully qualified (uop to worksheet, at least) range references

as follows

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdadd_Click()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sub")

    Dim i As Long

    With wks.Range("A8") ' reference "sub" worksheet cell A8
        i = 1
        Do Until .Offset(i - 1).Value = Empty ' check for referenced cell current row offset empty value
            i = i + 1 'keep a count of the ID for later use
        Loop

        'Populate the new data values into the 'Sub' worksheet.
        With .Offset(i - 1) ' reference referenced cell row offset to first empty cell
            'Populate the new data values into the 'Sub' worksheet.
            .Value = i ' set col A with next ID number
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.txtls.Text 'set col B
            .Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.txtPr.Text 'set col C
            .Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.cbolo.Text 'set col D

            Dim strApps As String
            For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
                If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then strApps = strApps & ListBox1.List(i) & ", " ' update 'strApps' string with listbox selected items separated by a comma and a space
            Next
            If strApps <> "" Then .Offset(0, 4).Value = Left(strApps, Len(strApps) - 2) ' if any listbox selected values, write 'strApps' in col E
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```